# C# WPF - Parent window jumps to top left corner of screen when Child window is shown

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I stop this from happening? My parent window just jumps to the top left part of the screen when ShowDialog() is called.

```
TransparentWindow trans = new TransparentWindow();
        trans.ShowDialog();
        trans.Dispose();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about stopping it, just change the title of your parent window to "Jumping Window" and document it as a feature.

Comment: Why do you call Dispose? The garbage collector will handle the resources automatically

Comment: @Jimmy: You makin' fun of my class names?
@Jamie: Cause I'm a baller.

Comment: Please show the XAML for the parent and child window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this. You need to first assign an owner to the Dialog.

Use this:

```
trans.Owner = this;
```

and then use the ShowDialog() method.
Remember to set the StartupPosition of TransparentWindow to CenterOwner.

Answer (score 0):

I think your window must be transparent to show up the parent window. 
If you call ShowDialog, it should go above the parent. You might also try for TopMost feature.

Are you calling the ShowDialog from the Parentwindow? I have been using this several times with WPF, and it works great to me.